# Springboot Scheduler runs 2 times and ends

Tags: spring-boot

I trying to start `Scheduled` job, but instead printing xxx every 5 seconds infinitely,  what happens is 'xxx' printed twice - on the same second (doesn't wait 5 secs)  , then prints 'EXIT' .

Why does it happen?

```
    @EnableScheduling
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class App implements CommandLineRunner{
    
        @Autowired
        private Job job;
    
    
        public static void main(final String... args) {
            try (final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
                    .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args)) {           
                
            }

            System.out.println("EXIT");
          
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            job.run();
        }
    }



    @Component
    public class Job {
       
        @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "5000")
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("xxx");
        }
    
    }
```

in console I only see:

z.r.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter   : Timed out waiting for in-flight spans to send.

o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the [@EnableScheduling annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) for enabling scheduled tasks capabilities. Additionally, you will need to change how you're using `SpringApplicationBuilder` as its scope (and lifetime) is currently limited by the try-with-resources statement. The following should work:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .build()
                .run(args);
    }

   [...]
```

Comment: sorry I had those annotations, didn't paste them by m mistake. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

The fixedRate immediately fires. Therefore if you want to wait for the initial run you should add initialDelay as follows;

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000,  initialDelay = 5000)
```

And when the applicaiton finishes the schedule cannot stop termination...

And of course @EnableScheduling is required...